# Trying to create a field in Google Data Studio that only counts if the name of a list begins with US

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to create a field in Google Data Studio that sums the revenue for lists that begin with US. I know I have to use regex, but it continue to tell me there is an unexpected end to the formula.

Here is the code.

```
    Revenue WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(List, '^US')
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(List, '^US.*')
                             ^^
```

Or even

```
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(List, 'US.*')
```

See [`REGEXP_MATCH` documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476?hl=en):

> - `REGEXP_MATCH` attempts to match the *entire string* contained in `field_expression`. For example, if field_expression is `"ABC123"`:
>     `REGEXP_MATCH(field_expression, 'A')` returns false.
>     `REGEXP_MATCH(field_expression, 'A.*')` returns true.